# instanceof Double/Object won't work :(

Tags: java, instanceof

I've got a problem with java's instanceof. Here's a gap of code that causes me trouble:

```
LinkedList<Double> currentSummary = summary.getFirst().getQuantiles();
```

...more code...

```
while (!currentSummary.isEmpty()){

        if (currentSummary.getFirst() instanceof Double){
            orderedSummary.add(new ComparableWrapper<Double, Float>(currentSummary.removeFirst(), currentEpsilon));
        }
}
```

So, my problem is, that the if-condition won't become true. Those elements in `currentSummary` are either `null` or an `Double`-value. And I'm trying to reject elements that are `null`. At first I just added them and ran into `NullPointerException` later on, because of some (but not all!) elements being `null`.
An example element of `currentSummary` is e.g. [null, 0.09861866469135272, 10.137051035535745, 107.12083740100329, 371.4371264801424, 827.432799544501, 1206.251577083686].

Anybody got's an idea why `instanceof` won't work in that case? I tried it with `currentSummary.getFirst() instanceof Object` as well...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not directly an answer, but since you don't seem to be removing the `null` entries from your linked list, won't this thing infinite-loop on the first `null` it encounters? Could you make sure `getQuantiles()` doesn't stuff `null` references into your list in the first place?

Comment: Does `currentSummary.getFirst() instanceof Object` behave different?

Comment: You could also try `currentSummary.getFirst().getClass()` to see what class the objects actually belong to.

Comment: No it doesn't. But that wasn't the problem at all. I just forgot to remove the first element if it is null. So I ran into an infinite-loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to remove the first entry at each iteration, in order to traverse the complete list. However, you remove the entry only when the instanceof condition is true. Therefore, it seems like the loop becomes infinite when it encounters the first null value (unless you dropped parts of the code, and we don't see the complete loop body)

Comment: Okay, it's definitely to warm at my place. The problem was of course the infinity-loop -.- Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that due to [auto-boxing/unboxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoboxing#Autoboxing), the Double objects get unboxed to the primitive `double`, and therefore they are not instance of `Double` class.

If that is the case, would it be better if you check for non-null elements instead?

Comment: Neither autoboxing nor autounboxing happens for an instanceof test.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a simple null check?

```
if (currentSummary.getFirst() != null){ ... }
```

Comment: I agree, but this doesn't explain why instanceof returns false for non-null values.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work at first. But you're right, that would work as well and looks much better ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, by using raw types (`LinkedList` instead of `LinkedList<Double>`), to add non-`Double` entries to your `LinkedList<Double>`. Those elements would fail the `instanceof Double` test. But those entries would pass an `instanceof Object` test.